# Overloading __eq__ in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, overloading

I'm trying to overload the == operator in a class, and this is the init method:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self._fields = ['a','b','c','d']
```

And I'm trying to overload the == operator, and here is my code for that:

```
    def __eq__(self,right):
        if type(right) == type(self):
            for i in self._fields:
                print(self._fields.index(i))
        else:
            return False
        return True
```

For == to be true, all the values in **init** should be the same. So if I have `test=Point(1,2,3)`, and then I have `test2 = Point(1,2,3)`, then test==test2 should return `True`. However, I have `test=Point(1,2,3)`, and `test2=Point(1,1,3)` and this is returning `True`. Can anybody figure out why this is?

Comment: This is still not your actual code, `if type(right) is not {type_name}:` will always be true as you're comparing `Point` with `set` here.(Considering you've defined `type_name` somewhere)

Comment: You are right. I have updated with my current code, where I try to use self.i as one of the answers said, but to no avail.

Comment: Your current code is doing nothing to compare `self` with `right`,  it will end up returning `True` when `right` is of type `Point`. Plus the `test2=Point(1,1,3)` initialization itself will fail due to incorrect number of arguments.

Comment: For next time: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I just want to say that my print statements were for debugging purposes, as I hope some people here realized.

Comment: People will answer or comment on the code you shared with us, that's why you can see different answers to your question, plus one guy had to delete their answer due to that.

Answer (score 2):

You're testing whether `self['a'] == right['a']` when what you want is `self.a == right.a`.  You should use the `getattr` function to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, all your code does while iterating over the fields is print out their indexes. It only will ever return `False` for objects of different types. Instead, you should use `getattr` to get the actual attribute values that correspond to the names in `_fields`:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return (self._fields == other._fields and
            all(getattr(self, attr) == getattr(other, attr) for attr in self._fields)
```

Note that I've changed the test for the two objects having the same type for one that checks that they have the same field (this is a kind of duck-typing). If you want to stick with a type check, I'd make `_fields` a class attribute, so you will know that every instance has the same value for it.

Alternately, you could do away with the `_fields` attribute completely and just hard code the attribute names:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return (type(self) == type(other) and
            self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b and
            self.c == other.c and self.d == other.d)
```